# random username generator

Tags: php, random

i am trying to create a random username generator.

i have looked at several random string generators, but none of them look like actual usernames.

i am wondering how i would go about creating a script like the one featured on this page: http://generator.my-addr.com/generate_usernames-free_username_generator_online_tool.php

basically takes a word from the dictionary, adds a certain number of random characters, and then adds a certain number of numbers.

my biggest problem is having it create realistic usernames.

Comment: Well, can you define a set of *rules* that make a username realistic or not? Write them down and I can help you from there.

Comment: why are you generating user names? won't email addresses be unique enough?

Comment: @DanielA.White Probably because they don't want to have an email activation system (to ensure their email is actually theirs). This is exactly the reason I found this SO entry. I'm starting to think email activation is going to be a better option, though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I don't see why you'd want to generate username, if your only concern is that they be pronounceable I would look into [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), which will allow you to randomly generate pronounceable words. You could look at the following projects for examples:

- http://passkool.sourceforge.net/
- http://shorl.com/koremutake

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for quick PHP solution to drop in, then I'd recommend:

[Mudnames](https://github.com/xrogaan/phpMudnames)

It generates fantasy style names from a set of dictionaries that you can find in the install readme. (I'd also throw a short salt in after the name, just to be sure it's unique.)